# Settings a View width same as other View

Tags: android, layout

I have a Linear Layout with 2 buttons of equal weights. So they occupy the whole screen(width wise).

In another Linear Layout below the 1st, i only have 1 button, whose width i want to be same as any 1 of the previous 2 buttons.

Is there a simple way to do, other than using gridview or tableview etc..,

I tried this:

```
Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);

three.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        one.getLayoutParams()));
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the 3rd Button is invisible now.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for second row

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/first1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width of the 3rd button in your java code, simply with the get and set width methods.

Get the width of one of your other buttons, and set that as width for the 3rd.

Secondly, your 3rd button is invisible because you don't have a root layout around your 2 LinearLayouts.

You should add a 3rd 'root' LinearLayout around it, with android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your third button to be invisible is because when constructing (and setting) a new LinearLayout.LayoutParams via

```
three.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(one.getLayoutParams()));
```

the weight is not transferred into the new LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

you could use following code to solve the situation:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams newlayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(one.getLayoutParams());
    newlayout.weight = 1;
    three.setLayoutParams(newlayout);
```

OR you could use another constructor ( [LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height, float weight)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20float%29)) , which takes the weight explicitly:

```
LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(one.getLayoutParams().width, one.getLayoutParams().height,((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) one.getLayoutParams()).weight);
three.setLayoutParams(param);
```

now three should be visible too.